# react + axios: obtener valor y colocarlo dentro del return

Tags: reactjs, axios

Hola poseo un contador de visitas en mi pagina y quiero mostral el valor de dicho contador dentro de un P o de un H1. No se como usarlo.
He intentado con APIS que devuelven varios valores como: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts y retorno los datos dentro de un map y me funciona bien.
Pero en este caso no hay ninguna lista de datos, ni map, el contador solo devuelve un valor.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function FetchingContador() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPost = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("https://api.countapi.xyz/hit/XXX.com/visits");
      console.log(res.data); // aqui me muestra bien el valor del contador
    };
    fetchPost();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <p> AQUI QUIERO MOSTRAL EL VALOR DEL CONTADOR </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Debes crear una variable de estado con useState y donde tienes ese consolelog asigna la respuesta al estado y en tu etiqueta p debes poner un conditional render que mientras que la variable de estado sea nula no renderize el p, algo como {!miEstado && <p>{mmiEstado</p>}

Comment: ok, gracias. lo probaré !!